# xfconf-query not working in crontab

Tags: bash, scripts, cron, xfce

i have a script as follow `/usr/bin/disable-sleep`

```
#!/bin/sh
xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -p /xfce4-power-manager/blank-on-ac -s 0
now=$(date +"%D %T")
echo "disable sleep $now" >> ~/cron.log
```

Then i have a cron record as follow:

```
0 6 * * * /usr/bin/disable-sleep
```

So in the morning i checked the `~/cron.log` and i see the log with correct timestamp, but the settings didn't change....

Comment: You might want to see https://superuser.com/questions/808555/why-is-this-cronjob-not-working and use `$HOME` instead of `~`.

Answer (score 2):

Jobs run through `cron`, or startup scripts, or `systemd` scripts, aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop. Startup scripts are run as `root`. None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings from `~/.bashrc` are automatically propagated to  your `cron` job. For example, there's no `$DISPLAY`, so GUI programs need special treatment (read `man xhost`).

One can set environment variables for all one's `cron` jobs in the `crontab` file
Read `man 5 crontab`.

Look at the results of  `echo "=== id ===";id;echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.
An easy way is to store the commands in a `bash` script, and execute it from your terminal session, saving the output, then, execute the script from the "other" environment, saving the output. Compare the saved outputs using `diff`.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "=== id ===";id
echo "=== set ===";set
echo "=== env ===";env | sort
echo "=== alias ===";alias`
```